# Spark DataFrame get all <p> xml tags from xml document per an element

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have this schema -for xml file- printed for a dataframe in Pyspark:

```
root
|-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _published-at: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- p: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

XML data looks like:

[image]

As you can see each article content is an html with < P> and < a> tags, the schema is detrmining the content of each article as an array of < P> tags, but when doing show data actually it's taking only the first < P> tag till the first < a> and the remaining content is ignored!

```
articles_df.select("_id", articles_df.p.alias('content')).show(truncate=False)

17 |[Chief juvenile probation officer ]
```

How can I assure to pick up all the content? (next step will be to format it without html special charterers like: & #32;)

I tried using my own customized schema, but getting the same:

```
link_structure = StructType([
    StructField("_VALUE", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_href", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_type", StringType(), True)
    ])

articles_schema = StructType([
    StructField("_id", LongType(), True),
    StructField("_published-at", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_title", StringType(), True),
    StructField("a", ArrayType(link_structure), True),
    StructField("p", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])

articles_df = spark.read.format('xml'). \
    options(rootTag='articles', rowTag='article'). \
    load('data-sets/articles-validation-small.xml', schema=articles_schema)
```

Comment: The problem is that the HTML inside XML is interpreted as XML by Spark, it should be encoded to not conflict with xml tags.

Comment: Thanks, make sense... so what do you suggest? to get rid of all <P> tags before reading/loading the file? it's a huge file and it will be not efficient. Is there a way to let dataframe ignore these tags for example?